# Eclipse connected to GDB but when my program crashes, nothing happens

Tags: android, eclipse, gdb, android-ndk

I've managed to build the Debug Configuration that targets remote client using GDB. This was done as per the Android NDK Sequoyah's plugin documentation.

After a few hours of tinkering I was able to get Eclipse to connect to the gdbserver on the device and see its crash through the console (verifying its connected).

But the problem is eclipse doesn't really do anything when it does. No stack trace, no highlighted problem code, nothing!

If anyone has any pointers on this I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks,
Kevin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get this working by using OS X instead of Fedora. Probably not a real answer though.